# Can't save in Vim for DOS in DOSBox

Tags: vim, dos, dosbox

I need to work in DOS, so I installed the 16 bit Vim ([downloaded from vim.org](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim71d16.zip)) in a folder using DosBox. 
When I first open a file it lets me save the file using :w.
I continue editing, and want to save again and it says it can't write the file!?
How can I fix this?
I am running Ubuntu. The file is in a folder with permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 7 metroxylon metroxylon 4096 Dec  7 12:30 src
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for help in the #dosbox channel at freenode. User Qbix, told me it is a DOSBox bug which will be added to the bug list.